# Botão salvar no tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Preciso saber como colocar uma função para o usuário ao clicar no botão Salvar, escolher o caminho e o nome do arquivo.
No meu programa o usuario digita algumas informações nas Entry e pelo Canvas gera um PDF com essas informações, img e linhas.
Eu consegui fazer o botão abrir a janela de salvar, mas na hora de salvar o PDF fica em branco e corrompido.

```
def save_relatorio(self):
    self.gerar_relatorio()

    self.arquivo = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.pdf',
                                            filetypes=(('Arquivos PDF', '*.pdf'), ('Todos arquivos', '.*')))
```

Se alguem poder me ajudar fico agradecido! Sou iniciante em programação.

Comment: a função que você disponibilizou somente vai pegar o nome e path do arquivo a ser salvo. Como você está salvando o PDF depois? Talvez você esteja salvando algo que não é um pdf como pdf e por isso o arquivo fica corrompido quando tenta abrir.

Answer (score -1):

Olhando o código que você passou, seu arquivo está em branco por quê supostamente você não está passando as variáveis no seu método `save_relatório`, Que deveria estar escrito assim:

```
def save_relatorio(self,informacoes,imagens,linhas):
```

Ai nessa função de salvar, você criaria o arquivo passando os dados que foram recebidos na função quando o botão foi acionado na tela anterior... O botão provavelmente vai estar escrito assim.

```
botao = Button(master, text="Salvar Arquivo", command=lambda:(save_relatorio(informacoes,imagens,linhas))).pack()
```

Lógica desta operação, ao clicar no botão você irá acionar uma função, mas para essa função ser acionada com as informações que você deseja, deve passar as mesmas como parâmetros na hora que for chamar a função com o botão.